# Problem with 504 Timeout Gateway in phpmyadmin using few INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, timeout, centos8

I have a problem with phpmyadmin on Centos 8.
I have four structurally the same table with "datetime" column.

I'm using this query:

```
SELECT `t1`.*, `t2`.*, `t3`.*, `t4`.*
FROM `table1` as `t1`
INNER JOIN `table2` as `t2`
ON `t2`.time = `t1`.time
INNER JOIN `table3` as `t3`
ON `t3`.time = `t1`.time
INNER JOIN `table4` as `t4`
ON `t4`.time = `t1`.time
LIMIT 10
```

This query I am using only in phpmyadmin.
Every try I get Error: 504, Gateway Timeout (rejected).

I was trying change mysql settings (max number of connections, query cache size etc.) but nothing works.
I noticed that when I am trying get result of query, server CPU rises to 90%. In addition, I have the same tables in localhost phpmyadmin where everything works very well and very fast. Here, on Centos, if I use only one INNER JOIN it works slower and only if I don't change LIMIT (what is also problem, I need more than 10 rows).

```
CentOS Linux 8.2.2004
Apache/2.4.37
MariaDB Server 10.3.17
PHPMYADMIN ver. 4.9.1
```

Comment: Do you have indexes on these tables? Please publish explain plan.

Comment: Tables have id with AUTO_INCREMENT. Cound you explain me what you mean about explain plan? My technical english is not very well.

Comment: Your query would almost certainly benefit if you add an index on time in all tables. and please read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html

Comment: So why does everything work smoothly on localhost if there I have tables also with index on id, not on time?

Comment: You aren't telling us anything about localhost or table size or providing explain plans so can't begin to approach an explanation of performance differences between hosts. Also a production host may be 'busier' and affecting performance.

Comment: Nevermind, it works! I would never have figured it out. Thank you very much @P.Salmon! Wish you all the best, greetings :)

Comment: Could you share the secret discovered?